# Isn't it possible that when we add the event handler for DOM Ready, it is too late?

Tags: javascript, browser, dom-events

Theoretically, isn't true that our code can add the event listener for DOM Ready, but when we add it, it is already too late?

For example, if we link to a `.js` file near the end of the `<body> ... </body>`, and the download time of that `.js` file is 2 or 3 seconds later, and the DOM has long been ready and the event already fired and all listeners notified, and now the JS code does

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM Ready event fired');
});
```

and it really is too late now, and the handler will never get called? In practice, it does not and should not happen, because then there would be weird behaviors. So how is this handled? Does the browser "retroactive" notify the listeners (even though the listener was added too late, the browser will notify it?).

Having said that, the "browser will notify the listener even if added too late" isn't true, if we register the DOM ready listener inside of the DOM ready handler:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  console.log('DOMContentLoaded event fired 01');
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM Ready event fired 02');
  });
});
```

Another way is when we load a page, and then in the debug console, type in

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM Ready event fired');
});
```

It is even true that if we missing the current event cycle, then it won't be called:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM Ready event fired');
  });
}, 0);
```

So what is the rule about if the listener is added too late?

Comment: *So what is the rule about if the listener is added too late?* - it won't fire

Comment: then what about if the DOM was ready, but just the external JS needing 10 seconds to download?

Comment: I simply answered your last (only) question - if you add an event listener for a specific event after that event has occurred, the handler won't be called - this is true of any event, since javascript has no access to Gallifreyan technology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't a problem.

The `DOMReady` event isn't triggered until all the HTML is loaded, which includes loading all the scripts. The exception is scripts with the `async` attribute; these are loaded in the background, and `DOMReady` doesn't wait for them. Scripts with the `defer` attribute are also loaded in the background, but the browser waits for them to load before sending the `DOMReady` event.

And if you use jQuery, you *can* use its `.ready()` function even after the DOM is loaded. If you call `$(document).ready()` later, it simply calls the function immediately, rather than adding an event listener.

See [Scripts: async, defer](https://javascript.info/script-async-defer) for an explanation of synchronous versus asynchronous loading of scripts.

Comment: so you mean if it is `<script src="abc.js" async></script>`, then the code in `abc.js` may "miss" the notification?

Comment: I thought DOM ready only involves downloading the HTML file and parsing and building the DOM, and not related to whether all external JS files are fully downloaded. (or the image files... JS and image files... those will be the window's "load" event)

Comment: Scripts are loaded synchronously unless they have `defer` or `async`. So it stops building the DOM when it's loading a script.

Comment: so you are saying... if the 1MB HTML file is download, parsed, DOM built, and content displayed to the user, at this point the DOM Ready event is still not fired. Not until all JS files are downloaded and finish executing... but it seems true: why fire the DOM ready event when nobody is listening to it? But I guess the key is **all JS code has to finish executing**

Comment: Yes. That's why you can sometimes see the page flash briefly when the JS finally executes.

Comment: so then if it is inside of some JS MVC framework, and you set the DOM ready inside of a class and the MVC framework doesn't instantiate your object until the next cycle, then you will miss the DOM ready event

Comment: It depends on when the MVC framework runs your code. If it runs your code in the DOMReady listener, then indeed that's a problem. But if you know that the MVC framework does that, you shouldn't put your code in the listener yourself.